# Jquery Animate Infinite Loop: How to Avoid Stack limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some Jquery that simply zooms in and out non-stop for a banner image.  When I run this, I get a stack limit error in the browser.  It still runs, but is there a way to make it only load into the stack "just in time"?  When looking at the stack it loads `zoomIn()` and `zoomOut()` over and over again on the initial load until it hits the limit, page loads are really slow because of it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $bannerImg = $('.post-picture img')

    function zoomIn(){
        $bannerImg.animate({
            width: 1500,
        }, 50000,'linear');

        $bannerImg.promise().done(zoomOut());
    }

    function zoomOut(){
        $bannerImg.animate({
            width: 1500,
        }, 50000,'linear');

        $bannerImg.promise().done(zoomIn());
    }

    zoomIn();

});
```

Update: Thanks for the answers.  Using done(ZoomOut/ZoomIn) worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.done()` expects a function reference - the function pass will be executed as soon as the promise object is resolved. Instead, you're just calling the functions (which return nothing, `undefined`, anyways). If you do this, the functions will continually call each other, acting as an infinite loop. Use this:

```
$bannerImg.promise().done(zoomOut);
// and later:
$bannerImg.promise().done(zoomIn);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/G6uWs/

(I had to change the numbers to make it usable)

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Answer (score 4):

You're calling the function in `.done()` instead of passing it as a parameter.

```
$bannerImg.promise().done(zoomOut());
```

should be

```
$bannerImg.promise().done(zoomOut);
```

and

```
$bannerImg.promise().done(zoomIn());
```

should be

```
$bannerImg.promise().done(zoomIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are causing an infinite loop. Luckily, the jQuery has a complete callback that you can leverage to prevent the infinite loop.

**Non-stop zoom in and out banner**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $bannerImg = $('.post-picture img');

    function zoomIn() {
        $bannerImg.animate({
            width: 1500
        }, {
            duration: 10000,
            complete: function () {
                zoomOut();
            }
        });
    }

    function zoomOut() {
        $bannerImg.animate({
            width: 100
        }, {
            duration: 10000,
            complete: function () {
                zoomIn();
            }
        });
    }

    zoomIn();

});
```

**Source: ** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44VxS/)